# Display image on multiple table rows in a newsletter

Tags: html, css, html-email

Is there any way to insert tilted image on multiple rows of table for newsletter email?

The early bird discount image is not positioning at corners of rows.
I sliced the image and tried with no avail, margin and position aren't working.

```
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;font-family: Arial;width:95%;max-width:600px;" bgcolor="e5f1e8" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="25"></td>
        <td>
            <table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img style="margin:0; padding:0; border:none; float:left;" src="http://www.neumannassociates.com/newsletters/HTML/images/header_03.jpg" alt="">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="background: #fff;" valign="top">
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                     <h1 style="font-family:Arial; margin:0; padding-top:9px; padding-left:24px; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; color:#ee7600; line-height:24px;">How To Value And Exit <br>
                                  Your Business For Maximum Profit</h1>

                                     <h2 style="font-family:Arial; line-height:20px; margin:0; padding:8px 0 10px 24px; color:#2b2b2b; font-weight:bold; font-size:15px;">An Informational Workshop For The Smart 
                                  Business Owner</h2>

                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <img style="margin:-16px 88px 0 0;" alt="" src="http://www.neumannassociates.com/newsletters/HTML/images/early1.png">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right" height="22">
                        <img style="margin:0 53px 0 0;" alt="" src="http://www.neumannassociates.com/newsletters/HTML/images/early2.png">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#ffffff">
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img style="margin:20px; float:left;" src="http://www.neumannassociates.com/newsletters/HTML/images/img3.jpg" alt=""><span style="float:left;width:70%; padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">
                <h1 style="font-family:Calibri; margin:0 0 10px 0; font-weight:bold; font-size:20px; color:#ee7600;">This event will demonstrate how to value a<br>
                  business and prepare a business for sale:</h1>
                <ul style="padding:0 0 0 18px; margin:0; font-family:Calibri; font-size:15px; color:#1e1e1e;">
                  <li style="padding:3px 0">Business valuations that withstand buyers’ negotiation pressures</li>
                  <li style="padding:3px 0">What is needed for a valuation and what are key ratios to value a business</li>
                  <li style="padding:3px 0">The right professional packages to attract capable, legitimate buyers</li>
                  <li style="padding:3px 0">How to qualify investors and which ones to avoid</li>
                  <li style="padding:3px 0">How to obtain a solid offer with the best deal structure for yourself</li>
                  <li style="padding:3px 0">What to do with Uncle Sam and what to look for in a closing attorney</li>
                </ul>
                </span>

                                </td>
                                <td valign="top" align="right">
                                    <img style="margin:0;" alt="" src="http://www.neumannassociates.com/newsletters/HTML/images/early3.png">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td width="25"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[JsFiddle for the template](http://jsfiddle.net/b77xce5f/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to be a bearer of bad news, but as far as HTML emails go, yours is not going to work well in most email clients. Email clients have a very 'special' way of reading HTML and CSS.  Tables are a staple and floats and divs as containers are mostly out.  Margin and padding can only really be used on TD tags effectively - and some clients won't even recognize margin at all.

Below are some links to help provide some good references and guides on the 'ins and outs' of email design and development.

https://www.exacttarget.com/products/email-marketing/email-design-toolkit
https://litmus.com/blog/html-email-coding-101-infographic
http://templates.mailchimp.com/getting-started/html-email-basics/
http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-code-html-email-newsletters/

**CSS capability among different browsers - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/**

I did also create a 'fix' on your issue, but keep in mind the rest of the email may fail in some email clients.  What I did is create a defined length TD to house the uppermost sliced image and then I made sure valign bottom was on for that one. On the next row, I created a new table in the TD with two columns. On the right TD, I again defined a width to place it.  On the final one I defined the TD width as well as set valign to top.

A major issue with the top one as well was the size of the row.  The height was larger than the image height, which mean it either would not connect to the top or to the bottom depending on valign. I made changes to font size and line-height in my sample to solve this.

```
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;font-family: Arial;width:95%;max-width:600px;" bgcolor="e5f1e8" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="25"></td>
        <td>
            <table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img style="margin:0; padding:0; border:none; float:left;" src="http://www.neumannassociates.com/newsletters/HTML/images/header_03.jpg" alt="">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="background: #fff;" valign="top">
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding:8px 24px 10px;">
                                     <div style="font-family:Arial; margin:0; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; color:#ee7600; line-height:22px;">How To Value And Exit <br>
                                  Your Business For Maximum Profit</div>
                                  <div style="height:7px; font-size:7px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height:100%;">&nbsp;</div>
                                     <div style="font-family:Arial; line-height:18px; color:#2b2b2b; font-size:13px;">An Informational Workshop For The Smart 
                                  Business Owner</div>

                                </td>
                                <td width="239" valign="bottom" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                                    <img style="display:block; border:none;" alt="" src="http://www.neumannassociates.com/newsletters/HTML/images/early1.png">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td align="left" width="144" height="22" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                        <img style="display:block; border:none;" alt="" src="http://www.neumannassociates.com/newsletters/HTML/images/early2.png">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#ffffff">
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img style="margin:20px; float:left;" src="http://www.neumannassociates.com/newsletters/HTML/images/img3.jpg" alt=""><span style="float:left;width:70%; padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;">
                <h1 style="font-family:Calibri; margin:0 0 10px 0; font-weight:bold; font-size:20px; color:#ee7600;">This event will demonstrate how to value a<br>
                  business and prepare a business for sale:</h1>
                <ul style="padding:0 0 0 18px; margin:0; font-family:Calibri; font-size:15px; color:#1e1e1e;">
                  <li style="padding:3px 0">Business valuations that withstand buyers’ negotiation pressures</li>
                  <li style="padding:3px 0">What is needed for a valuation and what are key ratios to value a business</li>
                  <li style="padding:3px 0">The right professional packages to attract capable, legitimate buyers</li>
                  <li style="padding:3px 0">How to qualify investors and which ones to avoid</li>
                  <li style="padding:3px 0">How to obtain a solid offer with the best deal structure for yourself</li>
                  <li style="padding:3px 0">What to do with Uncle Sam and what to look for in a closing attorney</li>
                </ul>
                </span>

                                </td>
                                <td width="95" valign="top" align="right" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                                    <img style="display:block;" alt="" src="http://www.neumannassociates.com/newsletters/HTML/images/early3.png">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td width="25"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the edits, my case sure is not working on small devices and different email clients. I learned few things from u, thanks for that. i guess i'll have to try a different thing.